# How to update ASP.NET boilerplate web application framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, frameworks, version

How to update the ASP.NET boilerplate framework with newer version of ASP.NET?

Latest version is 3.6.1: https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents.

Answer (score 2):

1- ABP v3.x is based on .NET Standard 2.0, which is only supported in VS 2017 15.3.3+.

- This concerns you regardless if you are on MVC 5.x, .NET Framework
  4.x or .NET Core 2.x.
- The [recommended version](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/Startup-Template-Core#introduction) is VS 2017 15.3.5+.

2- if you you are using 2017 VS and you want to update boilerplate packages must try to update ABP nuget packages via nuget package manager.

reference link link is : https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/3350